# UITableView - dynamic cell height controlled by cell itself

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uitableview, height

I have the following setup: UITableView with custom UITableViewCell implementation.  In each cell I have a UILabel and a UIButton.  When the table is first displayed, in each of the cells, the UILabel has the number of lines set to 1 and all cells have fixed height (60 px in my case).  When the button in the cell is tapped, then the UILabel's number of lines is set to 0 and word wrap is turned on, effectively expanding the table cell.

Now, the issue is that only the implementation of UITableViewCell knows whether the label is expanded or not - and thus what the cell height should be. However the owner file is the table's datasource.

I can't get may head around how to set this up.  Any ideas are appreciated.

**Update** here are extracts from my code

In the custom UITableViewCell implementation:

```
- (float)requiredHeight
{
    if(isFull)
    {
        CGSize labelSize = [LblTitle.text sizeWithFont: [LblContent font]
                                     constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(300.0f, 300.0f) 
                                         lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
        return 42.0f + labelSize.height;
    }
    else
    {
        return 60.0f;
    }
}
```

In owner file (UITableViewDelegate):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OOCommentCell *cell = (OOCommentCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [cell requiredHeight];
}
```

However this results randomly in an infinite loop or in BAD_ACCESS_EXCEPTION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after some struggling, here's what I ended up with, which kind of works.

1. I created a simple class to contain information related to one cell:

> ```
> @interface CommentInfo : NSObject
> {
>     int ID;
>     NSString *Name;
>     NSString *Date;
>     NSString *Content;
>     BOOL IsFull;
>     float Height;
> }
>
> @property (readonly) int ID;
> @property (readonly) NSString *Name;
> @property (readonly) NSString *Date;
> @property (readonly) NSString *Content;
> @property (readwrite, assign) float Height;
> @property (readwrite, assign) BOOL IsFull;
>
> - (id)initWithID:(int)_id withName:(NSString *)_name withDate:(NSString *)_date withText:(NSString *)_text;
>
> @end
> ```

Don't worry too much about all the properties - the most important one is the `Height`.

1. In my controller (which is also the delegate for the table view), I keep the data as an `NSMutableArray` of pointers to objects of type `CommentInfo`.
2. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I get the corresponding pointer and pass it to the custom cell implementation during construction, where it is stored.  I also set `self` as a delegate to the cell.
3. In the custom cell implementation, when I need to expand/change the height, I update the `Height` property in the `CommentInfo` object and call a method in the delegate to update the display.
4. When this `updateDisplay` method is called, I simple do the following:

> ```
> [CommentsTable beginUpdates];
> [CommentsTable endUpdates];
> ```

1. In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, I retrieve the corresponding pointer to `CommentInfo` and read the `Height` property.  As the pointer is the same between the controller and the cell, any changes to this property will be visible in both classes.

Job done.

Comment: I'm using a UIWebView inside a UITableViewCell, so it can't tell the height when the heightForRowAtIndexPath is being called.
What I do is I set the cell as a delegate for the UIWebView and in the webViewDidFinishLoad method I call [webView sizeToFit]; webView.hidden = NO; [tableViewController setRowHeight:webView.bounds.size.height forRowId:id]; and in the setRowHeight method of the UITableViewController i call these two methods you provided: [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates]; and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the method [UITableViewDelegate – tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) in your table delegate.  If you want to define height on a per-cell basis, you could 'forward' this call to the cell's class by calling your own tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Update: Implemented in code.  The error was caused by an incorrect method signature in the delegate calling tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

In the custom UITableViewCell implementation:

```
- (CGFloat)requiredHeight
{
    if(isFull)
    {
        CGSize labelSize = [LblTitle.text sizeWithFont: [LblContent font]
                                     constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(300.0f, 300.0f) 
                                         lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
        return 42.0f + labelSize.height;
    }
    else
    {
        return 60.0f;
    }
}
```

In owner file (UITableViewDelegate):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OOCommentCell *cell = (OOCommentCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [cell requiredHeight];
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'm following your logic.  I have defined `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, in it I tried to get the cell at the indexpath and then call a method in it to return the required path, however this results in bad_access_exception.

Comment: Essentially, the table is asking the UITableViewDelegate, "How tall should row X be?" via the method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:.  You should return a CGFloat of the desired height in pixels, not an index path.

Comment: @JacobJinnings: you seem to misread my code.  To "how tall should row X be", I'm trying to get that row X and ask it how tall it should be - and return that value.  Please have a look at the code more carefully.